# Selecting All Rows In UITableView , and Appending labels in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm able to select all the rows on button tap, However I want to append and remove the labels in that row to my array
I'm able to achieve this in `didSelectRowAt` and "didDeselectRowAt" for appending and removing respectively ! 
Code I'm Using is outSide The TableView Function.

```
func selectAllRows()
{
    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections
    {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
        {
            tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as? CheckableTableViewCell
            classesArray.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on the UI, rely on your model. I mean you wrote yourself `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so you know what you put in your `cell.textLabel.text`, just to the same to retrieve the value. Also, note that in your code, `cell` might be nil (read the doc of `cellForRow(at:)`) because it's not visible.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CheckableTableViewCell
        let classess = classes[indexPath.row]["classes"] as? String ?? ""
        let sections = classes[indexPath.row]["section"] as? String ?? ""
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(classess) - \(sections)"
        return cell
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as? CheckableTableViewCell
```

That's causing an issue because the `cell` might be `nil`.
See the doc of [`func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)

> **Return Value** 
>   An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range

Don't rely on UI, rely on your model.
In `tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt:)`, you do:

```
let classess = classes[indexPath.row]["classes"] as? String ?? "" 
let sections = classes[indexPath.row]["section"] as? String ?? ""
cell.textLabel?.text = "(classess) - (sections)"
```

Just do the same for `classesArray.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)`:

```
classesArray.append("(classess) - (sections)") //recalculate it like before
```

Comment: Thanks @Larme  this Helped me out func selectAllRows()
    {
        for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections
        {
            for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            {
                tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)

                let classess = classes[row]["classes"] as? String ?? ""
                let sectionss = classes[row]["section"] as? String ?? ""
                classesArray.append("\(classess) - \(sectionss)")
                
            }
        }
    }